# C# Stream.Write() runs into exception sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller, pushstreamcontent

I have a web service with a download functionality in an ApiController derived class. It reads a local file and passes it to a PushStreamContent, which cares for delivery to the requesting client.
This works mostly fine, but sometimes I get an exception which I don't understand in the call to outputStream.Write().

It says "**System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: 'Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.'**" and it comes mostly when I access a file, which is being opened for write by another process (where this process might append something, but in the situation of exception this doesn't need to happen). Anyhow this shouldn't matter because the file was successfully opened here and the last part was successfully read into my buffer.

```
response.Content = new PushStreamContent((Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context) =>
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[65536];
        var length = (int)stream.Length;
        var bytesRead = 1;
        while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
        {
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            length -= bytesRead;
        }
    }
},
"text/plain");
```

Note: In the debugger I see the outputStream is of type HttpResponseStream, it uses an InnerStream of type HttpListenerStreamWrapper.

So any idea what goes wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Consider replacing all this fairly dubious boilerplate with a simple `stream.CopyTo(outputStream)`. Not sure if that would fix your problem (or exactly what it is) but it seems like it wouldn't hurt, in any case.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - this approach simplifies the code fairly, but it doesn't help. My impression is it makes thing even worse (reproducible nearly 100% now)...

Comment: The only way this should realistically happen is if something else is setting the `ContentLength` (either directly or implicitly). You could try explicitly setting it yourself at the beginning (`content.Headers.ContentLength = 0`), if this errors out, you know something else is going on before your code, while if other code attempts to set it afterwards, that should error out. Check if there are any other paths that might be accessing the content or the output stream, as it could be a threading issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. My impression is helps a bit, but the same problem still exists...